# ts-jest and throwing errors when using strict mode

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

In my project I have `strict: true` set and everything works fine except for my tests that means I have to keep adding @ts-ignore to my tests because I get errors like "Object is possibly undefined" and while I appreciate TypeScripts enthusiasm I already know they might be undefined, hence why I'm testing them.

Is there any better way of doing this than what I've written bellow?

```
it('attaches hooks to upload collections', () => {
  const cs = cloudStorage(adapter)
  const initialized = cs(fakeConfig)

  // @ts-ignore
  expect(initialized?.collections[0]?.hooks?.beforeChange).toHaveLength(1)
  // @ts-ignore
  expect(initialized?.collections[0]?.hooks?.afterDelete).toHaveLength(1)

  // @ts-ignore
  expect(initialized?.collections[1]?.hooks?.beforeChange).toBeUndefined()
  // @ts-ignore
  expect(initialized?.collections[1]?.hooks?.afterDelete).toBeUndefined()
})
```

Comment: why you have to do optional chaining here?

Comment: because I'm not sure if those properties exist on the object

Answer (score 1):

If it's an error for any of these objects in the hierarchy to be undefined, I'd have separate assertions for each one as follows:

```
  expect(initialized).toBeDefined();
  expect(initialized!.collections).toBeDefined();
  expect(Array.isArray(initialized!.collections)).toBe(true);
  expect(initialized!.collections[0]).toBeDefined();
  expect(initialized!.collections[0]!.hooks).toBeDefined();
  expect(initialized!.collections[0]!.hooks!.beforeChange).toBeDefined();
  expect(initialized!.collections[0]!.hooks!.beforeChange).toHaveLength(1)
  expect(initialized!.collections[0]?.hooks!.afterDelete).toBeDefined();
  expect(initialized!.collections[0]?.hooks!.afterDelete).toHaveLength(1)
  // Repeat for collections[1]...
```

If you are confident the properties are *definitely* assigned, you could use `!` instead of `?` in your initial code:

```
  expect(initialized!.collections[0]!.hooks!.beforeChange).toHaveLength(1)
```